# Encoding mySQL text for HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently working on a database type website where some of the text it consists of is plain text such as apostrophe, copyright, reserved symbols, etc.

The database consists of 2000 plus entries. I am trying to come up with a quick and safe way to replace the unencoded plain text symbols and characters with encoded Ex: `&copy;` type characters to ensure the text renders correctly on the website.

I was thinking of something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
  if (strstr($row['description'], '©'){ 
       //replace with &copy;
  }
  if(strstr($row['description'], '\''){
            //replace with &#39;
  }
   ....etc...
  //once correct string is created, use mySQL to 
  // update $row['description'] for this row...
 }
```

I was wondering if this method will work to solve my problem? and if someone can help direct me in safe way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

The `htmlentities`() method is the appropriate way to do it.

See PHP Manual about [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Assuming my string is "johnny's toys are great ©" in my mySQL database currently. So will using htmlentities() be able to convert that string to a kind that will render correctly in HTML? or will I have to first store the string in the database using htmlentities, then use html_entity_decode before using the text on the website?

Comment: If you display it on your website, don't decode it. The browser does it.
You can do the htmlentities() when you insert in the database, that will make you do it only once per stored string.
You totally can do it after reading the string for the db, but that mean your server will do it each time a user wants to see it. It's a waste.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `htmlentities()` but don't forget to use `html_entity_decode()` while echoing back your text..

Comment: thanks for the reply. Assuming my string is "johnny's toys are great ©" in my mySQL database currently. So will using htmlentities() be able to convert that string to a kind that will render correctly in HTML? or will I have to first store the string in the database using htmlentities, then use html_entity_decode before using the text on the website?

Comment: When it is stored in the DB it looks like "johnny's toys are great ©", but when I try to echo the text on the site it has some gibrish characters in place of those special characters, instead of rendering as it is stored in the DB...

Answer (score 0):

To those having a similar problem, I found that this was the solution to my problem:

My content type was set to UTF-8 instead of the one below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Adding the code above to my html head tag automatically fixed the rendering problem.

Comment: it's good that it apparently has solved the issue but it is Not recommended to store special characters into database..